# Loop fires insert statement twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a a loop that iterates through the selections in an checkboxlist. The problem is the loop fires the insert statement twice for each selection. So if the user checks one box, it inserts 2 rows. If the user selects 3 boxes, it inserts 6 rows and so on. How can I make sure it only fires the insert once per selection??

```
protected void btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into t_ap_line_setup  (line,date) values (@line,getdate())";
    cmd.Connection = this.sqlConnection1;
    this.sqlConnection1.Open();
    foreach ( ListItem li in lines_list.Items ) {
        if (li.Selected == true) {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@line", li.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    this.sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Comment: When you run the code, what's the count of `lines_list.Items`?

Comment: Doesn't look like the loop is running twice. I suspect you click handler is firing twice. Maybe duplicate event subscriptions, or something.

Comment: just try 'if (li.Selected)' not 'if (li.Selected == true)'

Comment: @sajanyamaha what is the diff?

Comment: @vcsjones - You were right. I two event handlers for the the button click event. Post that as and answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like the loop is running twice. I suspect your click handler is firing twice due to duplicate event subscriptions.